# Node.js port listening and reading from stdin at the same time

Tags: sockets, node.js, stdin

I have a socket server in Node.js and I'd like to be able to read from stdin at the same time the server is listening. It works only partially. I'm using this code:

```
process.stdin.on('data', function(chunk) {
    for(var i = 0; i < streams.length; i++) {
        // code that sends the data of stdin to all clients
    }
});

// ...

// (Listening code which responds to messages from clients)
```

When I don't type anything, the server responds to messages of the clients, but when I start typing something, it isn't until I press Enter that it continues with this task. In the time between starting to type something and pressing Enter, the listening code seems to be suspended.

How can I make the server still respond to clients while I'm typing in stdin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just wrote a quick test and had no problems processing input from stdin and http server requests at the same time, so you'll need to provide detailed example code before I can help you. Here's the test code which runs under node 0.4.7:

```
var util=require('util'),
    http=require('http'),
    stdin=process.stdin;

// handle input from stdin
stdin.resume(); // see http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/process.html#process.stdin
stdin.on('data',function(chunk){ // called on each line of input
  var line=chunk.toString().replace(/\n/,'\\n');
  console.log('stdin:received line:'+line);
}).on('end',function(){ // called when stdin closes (via ^D)
  console.log('stdin:closed');
});

// handle http requests
http.createServer(function(req,res){
  console.log('server:received request');
  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
  res.end('success\n');
  console.log('server:sent result');
}).listen(20101);

// send send http requests
var millis=500; // every half second
setInterval(function(){
  console.log('client:sending request');
  var client=http.get({host:'localhost',port:20101,path:'/'},function(res){
    var content='';
    console.log('client:received result - status('+res.statusCode+')');
    res.on('data',function(chunk){
      var str=chunk.toString().replace(/\n/,'\\n');
      console.log('client:received chunk:'+str);
      content+=str;
    });
    res.on('end',function(){
      console.log('client:received result:'+content);
      content='';
    });
  });
},millis);
```

Comment: +1 for trying to reproduce and not finding any problems! I thought the code looked fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I must say I can also reproduce my problem with just this. It is sending every 0.5 seconds, but as soon as I type it is being suspended. When I press Enter, the messages are being sent again. It is perhaps helpful to mention I'm using Windows?

Comment: I recorded what I see with your example, are you seeing the same thing? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AeRQHn0z1g8

Comment: I do not see the same thing while running under Linux so it's more than likely an issue with the Windows Console blocking your thread.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061053/node-js-on-windows-when-and-why/6065653#6065653 for an explanation of the issues related to running Node under Windows.

Comment: @Rob Raisch: Thanks, that could be the problem indeed. As far as I can tell, there is no solution for this. Is that correct?

Comment: As far as I know, no there is not. You might try running the code to read stdin in a child process, but I'm not near a computer I could use to test. I'll try to poke around with it later when I am.

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that Node under Windows is really just *experimental* and certainly not ready for production.

Comment: Just wanted to say that with the native `node.exe` which is built for Windows, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your script as a background process using `&`? Otherwise the console is the controlling terminal of the process, and is probably sending a `SIGSTOP` message when you're typing to avoid race conditions or something.

Try running the process as `node myprocess.js &`

If it still happens, try `nohup node myprocess.js &`.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29)